# Appending to a dictionary of lists elements from a nested list in order

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, append

I've created a dictionary with keys that represent relative distances and values that are empty lists. I would like to populate these values--empty lists--with entries from a nested list that are the values of the relative distances. My problem is that when I populate the values of the dictionary, its entries are not being filled in the order in which they appear in the nested list.

This is the closest I've gotten to solving the problem:

```
relDistDic = { 'a':[], 'b': [] } # dictionary with relative distances

relDist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ] #nested list with dstncs

for v in relDistDic.values():
    for element in relDist:
        if len(v) < 2 :
            v.append(element)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
{ 'a':[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], 'b': [[7,8,9], [10,11,12]] }
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
{ 'a':[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], 'b': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] }
```

Any help or comments are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For starters, you should generally not treat `dict` objects as ordered, although they *are* ordered in Python 3.7+. However, the reason only your first two values from `relDist` is because you always start iterating from the beginning: `for element in relDist`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered! The order that you insert elements with *not* be the same order that they appear as when you iterate through them.

Not only that, but in

```py
for v in relDistDic.values():
  for element in relDist:
    if len(v) < 2:
      v.append(element)
```

For each value in `relDist`, you're only appending the first two (because of `if len(v) < 2`). Perhaps you meant to remove the items from `relDist` as you append them?

To do so, use `pop()`.

```py
for v in relDistDic.values():
  for i in range(2):
    if len(relDist) > 0:
      v.append(relDist.pop(0))
```

Comment: That would be ideal but I have yet to find a way to pop the first two elements into the first key 'a', and pop the remaining two elements into key 'b'.

Comment: Two great points! I think your second point is maybe more relevant to the specific behavior the OP is asking about, due to the fact that they are restarting the iteration for each element in the dictionary. Besides removing items, enumeration or a counter might also help solve the problem. The point about lack of order in dicts will definitely cause other unforeseen issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
relDist = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ] #nested list with dstncs

relDistDic = { 'a': relDist[:2], 'b': relDist[2:] } # dictionary with relative distances
```

Comment: This works for this simple version of the problem I am trying to solve.However, I could have anywhere from 13 keys to 96. If we take the 13 key dictionary as an example, I have a nested list with 29,952 elements that I want to distribute so: the first 2,304 I'd like to go into the first key, the next 2,304 into the second key, and so forth until I get to the thirteenth key and fill it up with the remaining 2,304 elements.